# How to make docker networking -- interfaces added using pipework persistent

Tags: docker

I have created the docker container and configured the network interfaces using pipework. But all the configuration is lost if the container is restarted. How can I can make this network configuration persistent so that it is applied automatically when the docker is restarted.

Comment: I dont know what is pipework. Do all the things as part of your dockerfile

Comment: If you can't automate this in a Dockerfile, you can always commit it using `docker commit` to save this state, see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit, and tag it with something specific, here is an example `sudo docker commit c3f279d17e0a  SvenDowideit/testimage:version3`

Comment: pipework script can be used to add network interfaces to docker like if you need more than one interface. pipework is run on docker host and not in the container and commit will not save that.

Comment: Can u post that pipework script?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make the interfaces persistent. When the container is started, the namespace is created and assigned to the PID of container. 
Once the container is stopped, the PID is lost and namespace is removed. So whatever the network interfaces and others created under the namespace are lost.